# Can Hasse-Minkowski be proved without class field theory?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Lam *Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields* declines to prove the Hasse-Minkowski Theorem in full (for forms over all number fields), saying "a full proof would usually involve some class field theory or else some deep arithmetic fact such as Dirichlet's theorem on primes in an arithmetic progression."

To judge from O'Meara 1973  *Introduction to Quadratic Forms*, though, Lam should have just said class field theory.  O'Meara notes on p. 187n that Dirichlet's theorem on primes in progressions has been used for proofs over the rationals, but not arbitrary number fields.

O'Meara puts it this way:

> Needless to say, it would be of great interest and importance to have
>   a direct proof of the entire theory (of quadratic forms on number
>   fields)

Has anyone later than that managed to prove the whole Hasse-Minkowski theorem using Dirichlet's theorem?

Comment: Serre, Cours d'Arithmetique (Ch IV Thm 8). It uses Dirichlet's theorem in the proof of the case of quadratic forms in four variables. Dirichlet is needed in the proof of an earlier theorem (Ch III, Thm 4).

Comment: I don't have it in front of me, but doesn't Serre restrict himself to the usual integers?  For general number fields, you can consult O'Meara's book on quadratic forms.

Comment: @AndyPutman Yes, you are right. I missed that part of the question.

Comment: Cassels' book "Rational quadratic forms" contains a proof (for $\mathbb{Q}$!) based on Dirichlet's Theorem in Chapter 6.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty: As I said, I recall reading a proof of the general case of H-M in O'Meara, but that was over a decade ago and I do not remember many of the details.

Comment: Perhaps this is not what you want, so I hesitate to write out a full answer in this direction (unless you'd like): using local-global properties of quaternion algebras over local fields, basically at the level of Weil's "Basic..." or less, and zeta functions of quaternion algebras, one can give a proof of Hasse-Minkowski over number field. Of course, the quaternion algebras are merely a different incarnation of the cohomological stuff that is part of classfield theory... and the zeta function stuff is not trivial. Let me know if this is new or of interest...

Comment: @paulgarrett Someone besides me upvoted your comment so it is interesting to people.

Comment: @paulgarrett  Yes I would like to see your kindof answer written out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So far the answer to the question is no.  Lam was speaking in very broad terms, and O'Meara's wish for a direct proof is unmet.

When Lam spoke of using the Dirichlet theorem on primes in progressions he may have meant proofs like Clark's [Quadratic Forms over Global Fields](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/qforms-global.pdf)

There the Global Square Theorem (saying a non-zero element of a global field is a square if it is a square at every place of the field) is quickly derived from the Cebotarev Density Theorem which is a generalization of Dirichlet's theorem.

The rest of that proof of Hasse-Minkowski uses the Hasse Norm Theorem which uses class field theory but this reasoning may be what Lam had in  mind.

Comment: For the proof of HM over Q, the case n = 4 is hard and is where Dirichlet's theorem on primes and the Hilbert reciprocity law over Q are used.  As Clark points out at the start of his Section 3, to prove HM over all number fields the case n = 4 is a simple consequence of the case n = 3 due to the technical ability to increase the base field (by a quadratic extension). Another treatment of HM that explains this simplification over number fields is Theorem 4.7 in Adam Gamzon's senior thesis at http://digitalcommons.uconn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1017&context=srhonors_theses.

Comment: The $n=2$ and $n=3$ cases of HM over general number fields (or global fields) are hard and that is where all the number theory (not just algebra) is needed in the proof.

Comment: I had been thinking of a proof using things akin to Hasse's norm theorem, although the quadratic case was due to Hilbert I think. Maybe the manipulation of local-global stuff about quaternion algebras and their zetas already counts as "too hard" in the context of the question...

Comment: @paulgarrett My own motive is not to avoid sophisticated arithmetic devices, but rather to restrict the logic: i.e. to limit what kinds of definitions of sets of numbers are used.  So some aspects of quaternion algebras are fine for my purposes.  But I think some people who like the question are also interested in finding elementary proofs in the sense of easier to follow.